# Has there been any attempt to learn the impact of replacement on win rate?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, simulation

Deck A is a 60-card deck, with each card present in only one or two copies.  Deck B is a 120-card deck, consisting of two additional copies of Deck A merged together.  As a simplifying assumption, let's say there are no cards in the decks that allow players to search; every instance of accessing the library is random.

Deck A and Deck B should function very similarly.  In terms of win rate against other arbitrary decks, my hypothesis would be that Deck A performs somewhat better, as it should tend to be bad, all else equal, to draw multiple consecutive copies of the same card or even card type (having lands and non-lands alternate seems optimal), and drawing a card in Deck B effectively only removes half of that card from the library, relative to drawing a card in Deck A.

We could extend this setup by merging any number of copies of Deck A, ignoring the actual game rules, and in the limit, the result should be identical to running Deck A, but drawing with replacement, instead of without replacement as trading card games are always played in reality.

Has there been any attempt to measure the impact of anything in this ballpark, either drawing with replacement versus without replacement or using the notion of partial replacement captured by merging a finite number of copies of a deck, on win rate?  I have seen a few A.I. algorithms trying to emulate games of Magic to compare the impact of specific decisions on win rate, and I was wondering if this has been tested, or if it is even possible to use mathematics to put some bound on the answer.

I find this question interesting in the analysis of Yorion decks, for example.  People often discuss the drawback of not drawing your best cards as often in larger decks, since the ratio of those best cards to total cards is lesser, but I am interested in how much of an additional detriment the replacement factor is.

Comment: To my understanding of mathematical terms, none of what you describe is "replacement."  (Cards which shuffle back into the library after being used would be replacement, and that's actually a mechanic...)

Comment: There is discussion about "deck thinning", which is reducing the likelihood that you will draw additional cards which are less desirable later in the game (like using a fetch-land to remove an additional land from your deck and improve your chances of drawing "business").

Comment: @Jedediah My claim is that if you take an arbitrarily large number of identical decks and shove them together into one huge deck (ignoring rule violations), drawing multiple cards from the huge deck without replacement is functionally equivalent to drawing multiple cards from one of the initial decks with replacement.

Comment: @Jedediah I'm guessing this is referring to a technical term from probability theory: to "draw with replacement" means to select a random element (a card) from a set (deck) without changing the probability of getting each element in subsequent draws. It doesn't necessarily mean that cards drawn would actually be placed back in the library.

Comment: I'm not sure of the math exactly, but I'm sure you can demonstrate that as the number of copies increases and you approach "drawing with replacement", you will see an increase in the variance of the distribution of the first N draws, for a fixed N. And I would say it is a generally accepted fact that consistency is valuable and variance is detrimental to winning games.

Comment: As a very simple example, if N=2, then if you draw from a 60-card deck, there are 60 possibilities for the first card, and 59 for the second. On the other hand if you consider drawing with replacement, there are 60 possibilities for the first card, and 60 for the second. So the first case is more constrained, and the difference increases as N increases.

Comment: I probably would have voted for ^ as an answer :P  Is the OP looking for specific MtG vs generic probability?  Not convinced this is a MtG specific Q now, just maybe bounded by Magic rules.

Comment: @joedragons murgatroid99 is indeed describing the distinction between replacement and non-replacement I had in mind.  What I'm hoping for in an answer is some research into how much of an impact this has on win rate, at least for a few example decks.  Similar questions have been approached via simulating actual games of MTG.